App fails to write to folder /Users/me/Test/
My macOS app gets an error when it tries to write to folder:  /users/me/Test/mv_data/.
I can manually write to a file there without problem.
I set permissions from /Users/me/ with this: sudo chmod -R a=rwx Test
Here's my system:

I run my Python script on my Mac which opens my Python GUI

I press START on the GUI which runs my macOS app executable

macOS app tries to write a file into Test/ but gets this error:

Error creating session directory: You dont have permission to save the file 2024-04-29T113328 in the folder mv_data.
Start session mv /Users/dbell/Test/mv_data/2024-04-29T113328
Start session /Users/dbell/Test/mv_data/2024-04-29T113328
Write to file:///Users/dbell/Test/mv_data/2024-04-29T113328/parameters.txt failed
Write to file:///Users/dbell/Test/mv_data/2024-04-29T113328/registers.txt failed



Here is Swift app code:
let pathString = dataDirectoryPath.path + "/\(serviceDirectoryName)"
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: pathString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    if logit(level: 0) { logit(LoggerCategory.warn, "Error setting up file captures: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
}

let sessionDirectory = (URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString).appendingPathComponent(sessionDirectoryName)).path

do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: sessionDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    if logit(level: 0) { logit(LoggerCategory.warn, "Error creating session directory: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
}


sandbox

"which opens my python GUI" -- do you mean that your script creates windows, dialogs, etc. or that you're running the script in a Python launcher or other app?

benwiggy- script creates windows, dialog etc, and a Start button which i press

Perhaps, when python-created GUI launches macOS swift app, there is some permission problem I'm not familiar with.

I've narrowed it down:  problem happens if i run app from Xcode:  can't create a folder -- says I don't have permission.  Seems like problem is with app's permissions to do file access.

re "sandbox – Joakim Danielson" --  It has been: "user Selected File Read/Write".  Anything else to change?
